# Select (keyword) from table

Tags: mysql, select

I have a table which contains information on places to fish. I have a column called species. its contents may be similar to:

```
Brown & Rainbow Trout, Pike
```

How do i write a statment that would show all fisheries that have 'pike' in the species column? something like:

```sql
SELECT species from table WHERE species='Pike'
```

of course this statment wont work becuase the species colomn contains more than just 'Pike'

Any suggestions? Without creating a column for each species.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using `LIKE`. (`%` means match 0 or more characters, `_` means match one character.)

```
SELECT species from table WHERE species LIKE '%Pike%'
```

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT species from table WHERE species like '%pike%'
```

Comment: % is a wildcard in SQL that means "any number of characters" -- so you're saying here that you want it to match any number of characters (including zero) followed by pike, followed by anything.  Another thing to note is that the 'like' keyword will also ignore case -- "Pike" will be found in this query.

Comment: @dweiss: actually like behaviour depends on field collation. If you use a case sensitive collation pike will be different from Pike.

Comment: I stand corrected -- thanks!  In my experience it's generally case-insensitive.  Is that usually the case?

Comment: By default mysql use a case insensitive collation if you don't specify it differently. Bye. :)

Answer (score 3):

Using `LIKE` instead of `=` in the `WHERE` clause below allows you match all `species` values that contain 'Pike'. It is a wild card search.

```
SELECT species
FROM yourTable
WHERE species LIKE '%Pike%'
```